# Sorting polygon elements with arcpy.SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, geometry, cursor, sorting

I'm wondering if there's a way to sort my records on the fly using a searchCursor.  I know you can't sort using the data access (da) module but can with the legacy function.

Without adding a record for the x,y of the polygon centroid as an attribute does anyone have any ideas?

I could grab the centroid point using SHAPE@CENTROID and then the resulting x,y with `@X` and `@Y`.  I don't think I can run those all together though, but if I did it would look something like:

```
arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, sort_fields="SHAPE@CENTROID@X a; SHAPE@CENTROID@Y a")
```

Comment: you can sort with the da cursors

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm check out the examples on the bottom of the page

Comment: I had not seen this before... can you post this as a solution so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Alternatively,albeit probably less efficient, is to run your data through the SORT tool, then step through that with a standard search cursor.

Comment: @Hornbydd that sounds like it would be taxing, especially on a large dataset. but yeah that would work too

Comment: The Sort tool is actually what you want with a large dataset -- "merge" sorts never run short of heap and fail for lack of gigabytes of free RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @ziggy this seems to be possible using the sample code at the bottom of the [arcpy.da.SearchCursor() documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm#C_GUID-3CB1DFF4-983D-445F-9CB2-0FF1CD4B4880).

> Use **`SearchCursor`** and the Python sorted method to sort rows.For
>   additional sorting options, see the [Python Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).